# How to tell the default device camera app to not take the biggest possible image, but a smaller one?

Tags: android

I am using the device camera like so:

```
private void checkWhetherCameraIsAvailableAndTakeAPicture() {
    // Check wether this device is able to take pictures
    if (isIntentAvailable(a, MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imageFile = null;
        try {
            imageFile = createImageFile();
            imagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 1*1024*1024L); // Limit image to 1MB
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            imageFile = null;
            imagePath = null;
        }
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Preferences.REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA);
    }
}
```

And then the camera opens and I take an image and I get a 50 MB bitmap file to work with, and trying to work with it results in a massive OutOfMemoryError.

As you can see I've tried limiting the file size returned to 1MB but apparently it doesnt work.

Now, I know that If I use a Camera.openCamera() object, I can set any parameters I like there, but how do I tell the device camera to take a bit smaller image than the maximum size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see I've tried limiting the file size returned to 1MB but apparently it doesnt work.

More accurately:

- `EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT` is not documented for use with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`
- Camera apps do not have to honor any particular extras, and there are thousands of camera apps

> how do I tell the device camera to take a bit smaller image than the maximum size?

You don't. Your choices are:

- Provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and get whatever the camera app wants to give you (typically the maximum resolution, though this might be configurable by the user in certain cameras)
- Not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and get whatever the camera app wants to give you (theoretically a thumbnail-sized image)

Comment: This is horrible. So I need to write my own camera using Camera.openCamera() and a SurfaceView if I dont want huge images thousands by thousands pixels big?

Comment: @J.K.: You are welcome to downsample the images yourself, using `inSampleSize` with your `BitmapFactory.Options` when you load in the image. This has nothing to do with third-party camera apps, but rather any image source that you do not control (e.g., images downloaded from the Internet).

Comment: Well, this is what Im doing at the moment - downscaling/downsampling the images, the problem is the shock coming from the initial bitmap that I receive which is huge.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it seems to be super simple to use the default camera app to capture a picture, but there are many pitfalls. I wrote a little helper to deal with all the different implementations by Android device manufacturers and Android versions: https://github.com/ralfgehrer/AndroidCameraUtil

Moreover, there is a great library to load and cache images: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

If you combine the two libs you don't have to worry about file size etc.

Comment: I will make sure to check this out!